# What are the costs of using ExpandoMetaClass.enableGlobally()? (Groovy)

Tags: grails, groovy

I want to be sure I am not going to cause a performance issue with this. We are writing a simple Money DSL and I was advised to turn on:

```
ExpandoMetaClass.enableGlobally()
```

However, I cannot determine yet exactly what this means. Does it *only* enable metaclass overrides on the inheritance tree for the root object, or does it apply it to every object type in memory?

Are there risks to applying Expando globally to a production instance?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Grails does this already, so whatever cost is involved is already incurred :)

This setting changes the default `MetaClass` implementation from `MetaClassImpl` to `ExpandoMetaClass`. `ExpandoMetaClass` was written by Graeme for Grails to make it easier to dynamically add methods to the metaclass, e.g.

```
String.metaClass.bark = { -> println "WOOF!" }
```

and it was added to Groovy core years ago.

Comment: Thanks Burt - that answers my concerns. Just saw a few of your talks recently - really enjoyed your "best worst practices" presentation. Haha!